# Xcode 4.4 Connecting a .h and .m to a View Controller

Tags: xcode4.4

I'm using Xcode 4.4 and I'm trying to connect the .h and .m files to the view controller in my storyboard but the options I have for adding files are:
Objective-C class
Objective-C category
Objective-C class extension
Objective-C protocol
Objective-C test case class

Every tutorial and answer I have found is for the 4.2 version which goes the option of Objective-C subclass which I don't have. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it in 4.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and just found the answer.
First, make sure to read Xcode help about storyboard (in help menu, type story...)
Second, Make sure XCode show you his full interface (in the tool bar, select all three view icons, or at least the bottom right and bottom left icon.

There is a video in the help which explain how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

why you have to connect  .m and .h to the view controller ?
try the easy way: file - new file - objective c class and in the second windows check "with XIB interface".
with this, you'll get .m .h and .xib !